# Webshot() not working with wordcloud2() when figPath parameter is passed in r.

Tags: r, text-mining, word-cloud

I am using webshot to save the html widget created by wordcloud2 but whenever i pass a png file to the figPath, i get a blank image. I can see the wordcloud if i open the .html file but the png created by webshot is blank. It works fine when figPath = NULL. I can't figure out why this is happening.

Here's my code :

```
library(wordcloud2)
library(RColorBrewer)

File <- "image.png"
library(webshot)
library(htmlwidgets)


graph <- wordcloud2(freqdf, size=clsize, color =clcolor, backgroundColor =clbgcolor,
                  figPath = clfigpath) 

saveWidget(graph,"tmp.html",selfcontained = FALSE)
webshot("tmp.html",File, delay = 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that FigPath is the path to your image mask. You should try something like this:

```
    wordcloud2(freqdf, size=clsize, color =clcolor, backgroundColor =clbgcolor, figPath = "image.png")
```

Also, there's a known bug that the package creator is aware of. To get around the bug, you need to refresh the viewer or open it in the browser. See this [github issue](https://github.com/Lchiffon/wordcloud2/issues/12) for the package creator's explanation.

Hopefully that helps.